# malloc() with heap overflow explanation

Tags: c, heap-memory, buffer-overflow

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int bufferSize = 8;
    //Setting the buffer size here, which can cause a heap overflow
    char *argsStr = malloc(bufferSize);
    char *anotherStr = malloc(bufferSize);

    //If argv[1] is greater than the buffer size, we will have an overflow
    strcpy(argsStr, argv[1]);

    printf("String 1: %s String 2: %s", argsStr, anotherStr);

}
```

I want to cause a heap overflow, so I import the param 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest'.

I would expect, since argsStr is only of size 8, it would be 'testtest' and the rest would overflow into anotherStr (for 8 bytes), but instead I see:
[image]

so argsStr is 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest' and anotherStr is 'testtesttesttesttest'

Why is this? Am I missing something with heap overflows or `malloc()`?

Comment: Why do you think sequential calls to `malloc()` allocate sequential memory blocks?

Comment: typical implementations of malloc will return a larger block than requested ... your gdb output indicates a 16-byte difference in this case

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`printf()` doesn't know or care how much memory you allocated for the buffers. When it's printing a string with `%s` format, it keeps printing until it reaches the terminating zero byte. So when it's printing `argsStr`, it prints the entire thing, even though it overflows the 8 bytes that were allocated. This is why buffer overflows are a problem -- C pointers don't include any information about how much memory is allocated, so you can easily access memory outside the allocated space if you don't check your lengths correctly.

The memory for `anotherStr` was apparently allocated 16 bytes after the memory for `argsStr`. So when you printed that, it started from the location of `argsStr[16]`, and printed the last 20 bytes of that string.

This is all undefined behavior, of course, so you can't depend on any specific result.

Comment: Corner case: "printf() doesn't ... care how much memory you allocated for the buffers." --> Almost.  Output more than 4095 may be  subject to an _environmental limit_ C11 §7.21.6.1 15

Comment: @chux That's still more about where the null byte is than how much memory was allocated.

Comment: So does gdb's print statement mimic printf? I would expect the p statement to take memory into consideration

Comment: @StanleyCupPhil What does "take memory into consideration" *mean*?

Comment: @StanleyCupPhil If it were an array, it could take the size from the array declaration into consideration (I suspect it does, but I'm not sure). But it's a pointer, so there's no size available to the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect, since `argsStr` is only of size 8, it would be `testtest` and the rest would overflow into `anotherStr`

In order for the `argsStr` string to stop after 8 characters on printing, 9-th character must be `'\0'`. Your string does not have it, hence `printf` does not know to stop after printing the first 8 characters on `%s`.

You got your heap overflow, because `strcpy` blew past the allocated size. It also blew through the "bookkeeping info" stored by `malloc`, and spills into the next allocation. Of course it does not have to go into the next allocated block, because it's undefined behavior; it just happened to do it on your particular system.

You can tell that there was a heap overflow by running your program through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Chances are, your program is going to crash when you add calls to `free` the memory that you allocated.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, when you do a malloc, it gives you a pointer to a block of memory in the heap.  The exact structure of the heap is implementation dependent.  As others have observed, you may or may not get sequential memory and you may or may not get exactly the amount of memory you asked for.  There are debug implementations malloc that give you the memory you asked for plus a big area at the end with markers to allow finding when you overwrite the end of your allocated block.  Something else to keep in mind is the second malloc could be either before or after the memory for the first malloc. Like MM observed, you could do a %p to see where the blocks are located to get an idea if they can run into each other.

This is what is called undefined behavior.  Exploring undefined behavior is great fun and allows you to get insights into the implementation but don't be surprised if it changes with a different version.  You can almost be guaranteed that it will change substantially on different systems, even with the same (GCC) compiler.

If you are really interested, you could find the source for the GCC run time library malloc routine on the web and see what goes on inside.  I just searched for "gcc runtime library malloc source" and found something that will take more than a few minutes examination to make sense out of.  It is pretty awesome code.  A lot of very smart people spent a long time working on it.

Comment: Most of that is true, but `malloc` is implemented by the C standard library (`libc`) not by GCC

Comment: Quite so.  For what it is worth, I found some malloc glibc source at:  [link](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html).